# Creating a fair coefficient for prize competition

Tags: mathematical-statistics, diversity

I am trying to boost sales in our sales divisions by creating a small competition between them. However, the elaboration is quite tricky in order to guarantee a fair competition. 
There are 20 sales divisions. They differ in size, potential and employees. 
During a given time frame, they should generate as much volume as possible, with as many customers as possible. The focus is primarily on the volume. There is an upper limit at which the competition stops (10 mil over all SDs). This means that SD1 has the potential to do >20 mil with 474 potential new customers while SD18 only has the potential of 600k with 16 new customers.
I am trying to create an equitable ratio to rank them. However, I just cant wrap my head around it. 
SD1 has the highest potential, most customers and most clerks. They obviously generate more business than smaller units.
SD18 is the exact opposite.
If SD18 generates 300k new volume, they are obviously doing better than SD1 generating the same amount. SD1 also has to generate volume in the amount of half their potential to be equally good. However, if SD18 does more than half their potential, SD1 cant, because the competition is capped at 10 mil.
How do I compare these units?
Is there a way to create a ratio that takes New Volume (weighted at 60%), New Customers (weighted at 40%) and the number of Clerks into account?
Should I focus on something else, e.g. new customers only?
What could be a fair coefficient?
[image: Random sample]